# Docker / Postgres - Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to create a container using this command, but, as soon it gets ready, it don't get a port, so, i can't run the spring project, as follows bellow:

diego@diego-Aspire-A515-54G:~$ sudo docker run --name dio-cities-db -d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres_user_city -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=super_password -e POSTGRES_DB=cities postgres
7a7f7eed14493f91edf49c0ee8dfd28a7a43b87d4952f5c24303d5e777f09274
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dio-cities-db (4bb2ebb46e5451f6d088f2d65419732ceb4711071e5e936e877e160b999943e9): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use.

I've been searching a lot but i can't solve it...i appreciate any support, thanks.

Comment: That error message means the standard PostgreSQL port 5432 is already being used by some other process, either a PostgreSQL server running outside Docker or from a similar `-p` option on another container.  You may be able to change the `-p` option (only the first number, the second must be 5432); or remove it if you're only contacting the database through Docker networking; or find the other server/container and stop it.  The linked question has more suggestions and details.

Comment: Thank you David, i did switch to port 5431 and it worked well.